# How to treat packets emited locally equally to those received via network (iptables)?

Tags: iptables, routing, nat

If a network packet is emitted by a local IP (an IP set to a  network interface in the system), it is treated differently to those packets that arrive via the non-locally (i.e. via the network)?

An example of that would be that the `iptables` `NAT` table chain `PREROUTING` is valid for *non-local* packets, however for `nat`-ing *local* packets the `OUTPUT` chain is used. I do not know really why this is? However I wonder and ask here:

Is there a way to change this (i.e make *local* packets go through the same iptables chains as *non-local* packets)?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve this, but what would be a use case for this?

Comment: Usually you work around this by running an application in a network namespace, changing it into a non-local peer.